# Si una linea de log contiene una sentencia extraer la IP

Tags: regex

Linea de log

```
2020-09-02 12:17:28 140109068834560 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'121.127.253.68' (using password: YES)
2020-09-02 12:17:45 140109068834875 [Warning] Access denied for user 'kikoveneno'@'121.127.253.68' (using password: YES)
```

Soy bastante duro con el Regex. Lo se. Estoy intentando extraer la IP (esa parte si la obtengo), pero me siento incapaz de verificar que la linea tenga la cadena 'Access denied for user' y que el usuario sea cualquiera pero que exista 'user'

Extraer la Ip o saber si la Ip existe.

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

Verifica si existe el grupo user

```
(\'([a-z]*?\'))
```

Pero no se "empalmarlo" y tampoco se como verificar que **Access denied for use** exista

Lo intentado en https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No esta tan complicado, solo tienes que unir las cadenas de busqueda e iniciar con user.

Esto te serviría, aunque existen mejores formas de extraer la IP; en este caso igual no creo que tengas problemas.

```
user\s('([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'\@'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')
```

Agrego ciertos parentesis para que te ayude a obtener los valores con los grupos.

```
0 = todo el string 
1 = user
2 = ip
```

Puedes ver eso facilmente en la web de regex101 te dejo el link al test en regex101.
https://regex101.com/r/uG3hLD/1

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 1):

Para encontrar la la cadena 'Access denied for user' puedes usar el token `(?:)` que te permite encontrar literalmente la cadena que contenga,

```
(?:Access denied for user )
```

Y como ya menciono @Jhoubert puedes combinar la forma en la que encuentras el ip y el user para encontrarlo todo de una sola vez

```
(?:Access denied for user )'([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)'\@'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'
```